# Android - Register a dynamic number of textviews

Tags: java, android, textview, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to figure out to how to tell which TextView is clicked. I have a different amount of them each time and I'm trying to figure out how to tell which one was clicked. Thanks

```
    ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    sv.addView(ll);
    for (int i =0; i < myArray.size(); i++) {
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText(myArray.get(i).toString());
        tv.setOnClickListener(this);
        ll.addView(tv);
    }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    //how do I tell the textviews apart?
}
```

Comment: Use either a custom `View` that has a name or identifier field or use the ones supplied by Android: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#View (`Tag` or `Id`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this:

```
    ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    sv.addView(ll);
    for (int i =0; i < myArray.size(); i++) {
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText(myArray.get(i).toString());
        tv.setTag("myTag_"+i);
        tv.setOnClickListener(this);
        ll.addView(tv);
    }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    String tag = v.getTag(); // is myTag_6 for example


    //how do I tell the textviews apart?
}
```

Comment: This worked except I had to make v.getTag() return a string. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

The `View` parameter of the `onClick`is the View that was clicked. So if the `TextView`s have different IDs you could do this

```
public void onClick(View v){
     switch(v.getId()){
         case R.id.text1: //textview with id text1 was clicked
     }
}
```